# Is there a way to flush docker's embedded dns cache?

Tags: docker, debian-jessie, docker-compose

I'm working in an environment where sometimes the DNS server flakes out and tells you it can't resolve a host (eg. lookup of "github.com" fails).  It's transient, and usually recovers fairly quickly.  However, sometimes when it happens, it seems like the [embedded DNS service the docker daemon provides on user-defined bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/configure-dns/) will cache the bad result.  Once it's been cached, we end up needing to remove the network entirely and rebuild it (ie. `docker-compose down`, then `docker-compose up`).  I'm seeing this on a debian jessie box, running docker-engine 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be.

Has anyone else encountered this, and maybe figured out a lighter-weight solution than having to tear down and rebuild the network?